# Sagem 802.11g Cardbus (Wpcb-165g(R)) driver

Tags: 11.10, wireless, drivers, 12.04

Where can i find Sagem 802.11g Cardbus (Wpcb-165g(R)) driver  and how can i install it on ubuntu 11.10 and ubuntu 12.04 alpha 2

Comment: What chipset does the card use? Can we see block about it, in the output of `lspci -v`?

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=958305) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/b43), looks like all you need is the b43-legacy driver. Do so by running `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer`. If you do `lspci`, you should see your wireless adapter with the vid/pid: 14e4:0018. If that fails, consider `ndiswrapper` if you have the windows driver on disc, because finding it online may be extremely difficult.